Install Visual Studio 2022 using PowerShell way
I am trying to install Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 from an offline package version as per the link
I have downloaded the layout as offline copy and trying to install the Visual Studio on a non-internet machine. I want to use this PowerShell automated way for the installation and un-installation.
PowerShell command used:
$Arguments = "'--noWeb', '--quiet', '--norestart', '--force', '--wait', '--lang en-US Ja-jp Ko-kr', '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop', '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb', '--includeRecommended'" 

(Start-Process -FilePath "C:\VSLayOut\vs2022_enterprise.exe" -ArgumentList $Arguments -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode

When running the above PowerShell command, it always pops the UI to continue with the agreement and installation using the UI. It was supposed to run the silent way, but seems like its not working the expected way. How can I run the PowerShell command in an automated way without manual intervention?

Does it work if you run it under an admin account?

Yeah, I am running this Powershell command through an admin account only.

Don't embed arguments escaped into a string.  -ArgumentList takes a list of arguments as a string array.  Remove your encapsulating double-quotes and it'll work.

Thanks, I removed the embed arguments and additionally I had to remove the --lang parameter which fixed the problem.

I removed the embed arguments and additionally I had to remove the --lang parameter which fixed the problem.
$Arguments = "--noWeb --quiet --norestart --force --wait --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --includeRecommended"

(Start-Process -FilePath "C:\VSLayOut\vs2022_enterprise.exe" -ArgumentList $Arguments -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
